# How to get a SourceSet from a DefaultAndroidSourceSet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This is the `build.gradle` file in the root of an Android Studio project with multiple modules, one of which is is an android app, ie it has the android plugin.

**Code**

```
subprojects.collect { p ->
        if(p.name == "app") p.android.sourceSets.main
        else p.sourceSets.main
    }
```

**Issues**

First, I need to hardcode the name of the android project so I can use the different API since `sourceSets` is not directly exposed on a project that has the android plugin installed.
Second, `android.sourceSets.main` does not return a regular `SourceSet`, it returns a `DefaultAndroidSourceSet` which is a completely different type. I haven't found a way to convert.

Any ideas how to solve the second issue? Would also be nice to solve the first one but it's not as important. Thank you.